# How to merge multiple rows in Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheet with columns along the lines of:

```
URL | Pageviews | Time on Page
```

The same URL is sometimes on multiple rows and I'd like to merge the two other columns together so that the data is aggregate for each.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to merge all the data per URL or for the last two columns?

Answer (score 1):

In a new adjacent column, let's call it `Merged`, add the `JOIN` formula. Below is an example with `=JOIN(" and ", B2, C2)`. Then drag to duplicate the formula in the rest of the column. In your case you might use a comma `", "` instead. But that's the gist of it.

[image]

More info on the formula **[here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077)**.